# Why should the accepted answer be always the first listed?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

It often happens to see accepted answers with very few votes floating at the top of the list before much more voted ones.

Actually which answer is more pertinent to the community ? The accepted one or the one with the most votes ?

Is there a good reason to emphasize **an accepted answer with 1 vote** vs **an other answer with 100 votes** ?

Comment: Valid discussion, but already discussed. Looking for the dupe.

Comment: Damned I didn't see this one... Thanks